# Плагин, который при наведении на фото будет показывать текст

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли плагин для wordpress, который при наведении на фото будет показывать текст. Пример [здесь](http://cheektochic.com/).

Comment: Это делается без плагинов, просто надо хорошо верстать

Comment: @cema93, вы правда думаете, что этот ответ сильно поможет автору вопроса?

Comment: По моему нет, можете только кастомизцию шаблона заказать.